# ansible varibals do not pass to include_role

Tags: ansible

i have this ansible structure its part of large code base :
it seems that when running the main playbook the defaults/main.yml app_type:game
don't pass on to the current_version.yml and give error
why it doesn't use the default var in defaults/main.yml

also when i pass the same variable name from --extra-vars it gives me the same error
when i print the variable from tasks/main.yml
it prints the right value
what is wrong with the include_role?

```
C:.
├───defaults
│       main.yml
│
└───tasks
        main.yml
        current_version.yml
        legacy_version.yml



    
main.yml    
---
app_type: game  
    
tasks/main.yml

#- name: set lagacy_package true
#  set_fact:
#    lagacy_package: true

- name: select legacy
  include_role:
    tasks_from: legacy_version
    name: package_install
    public: true
  vars:
    app_type: "{{ app_type }}"
  when: (lagacy_package is defined) and (lagacy_package == true)

- name: select Current
  include_role:
    tasks_from: current_version
    name: package_install
    public: true
  vars:
    app_type: "{{ app_type }}"
  when: lagacy_package is not defined
  
  
 current_version.yml
 
 - debug:
    msg: "System 2  ################ {{ app_type }} ######################################## "
```

error from current_version.yml

```
2020-07-01 17:04:09,118 p=11546 u=ec2-user n=ansible | fatal: [10.0.5.71]: FAILED! =>
  msg: 'An unhandled exception occurred while templating ''{{ app_type }}''. Error was a <class ''ansible.errors.AnsibleError''>, original message: An unhandled exception occurred while templating ''{{ app_type }}''. Error was a <class ''ansible.errors.AnsibleError''>, original message: An unhandled exception occurred while templating ''{{ app_type }}''. Error was a <class ''ansible.errors.AnsibleError''>, original message: An unhandled exception occurred while templating ''{{ app_type }}''. Error was a <class ''ansible.errors.AnsibleError''>, original message: An unhandled exception occurred while templating ''{{ app_type }}''. Error was a <class ''ansible.errors.An
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in the below code of "select legacy" task which is going to a loop for assigning `app_type` with itself.

```
app_type: "{{ app_type }}"
```

Changing the name of either of the variables should work like:

```
app_type: "{{ other_app_type }}"
```

Comment: do you mean to change it to different name?
like 
app_type_x: "{{ app_type }}"

Comment: Or, `app_type: "{{ other_app_type }}"`